# OutOfMemoryError - can I dump data into file instead of memory?

Tags: java, performance, memory-management, out-of-memory

I'm using an API that provides a method like `remoteConnection.getObjects()` to get a list of objects from a remote server. The list is sometimes huge and causes a Java heap space OutOfMemoryError. Is there a way of dumping these objects directly to a file rather than have them loaded in memory?

Comment: Yes, but it depends on the API - if the API attempts to loads them all into an array and return you that array then there isn't much you can do about that (except ask to get the API changed)

Comment: Yeah rubbish API unfortunately. Also closed source and there's no other option but to stick with it.

Comment: Quite an interesting question. If you are not going to call that method very often, and do not mind about performance, in theory you could load the separate virtual machine and let it use huge block of swap memory to load the objects and write into file. Never tried anything like that but I think it is possible that it could work.

Comment: Thanks Max. Didn't know that's possible - will have a look

Answer (score 5, accepted):

From what you have described, unfortunately the answer is **no** you cant - "Out of Memory" doesn't actually mean that you have run out of physical memory, it means that your virtual address space is too full / fragmented to allocate any more.

In short - paging bits of memory to disk won't help you because physical memory isn't the bottleneck, the limiting factor is simply the ability to address memory. (The OS will already be seamlessly paging memory to disk for you).

Your options (that I can see) are:

- Lobby the API developer to change their API, or find an alternative way of using the API that returns the data in smaller chunks
- Attempt to increase your available address space by either:

  - Reducing your existing memory use as much as possible
  - Increasing the address space (e.g. target x64)

Comment: Ah very interesting, thanks for the explanation. I don't think I'm left with many options then

Comment: nice answer. better than mine ;) +1

Answer (score 3):

unfortunately you can't do much if it's the API returning that amount of data.  **Can you increase your heap size using the -Xmx jvm arg?**

Comment: I did but apparently 150k trades won't fit in 2g

Comment: Wow 2gs for a 150k objects and they still don't fit!  I'm sure the API developer could change this considering the bandwidth size alone.